# Clean www.test.com to test.com

Tags: python, regex

I currently use the following method to clean websites.

```
http://www.example.com > example.com
https://www.example.com > example.com
http://example.com > example.com
```

However,

```
www.example.com > www.example.com
```

How can I make sure, www.example.com turns into example.com

```
import re

website = "http://www.example.com"
def clean_website(website):
    """
    Transform http://google.com, https://google.com, http://www.google.com and
    https:www.//google.com into google.com.
    """
    url = re.compile(r"https?://(www\.)?")
    return url.sub("", website).strip().strip("/")

clean_website(website)
```

Comment: Regex all what after second slash !

Comment: Please use example.com or *.example for examples because they are reserved for that kind of [purposes](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606).

Comment: I changed that @Wouterr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tldextract

```
import tldextract

def clean_website(url):
    # Example of ext if input is http://www.test.com
    ## ExtractResult(subdomain='www', domain='test', suffix='com')

    ext = tldextract.extract(url)

    return '.'.join(ext[1:]) # domain + suffix
```

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
import re

website = "http://www.test.com"
def clean_website(website):
    r = "^http.*\/\w*.?"
    x = re.findall(r,website)
    for i in x :
        website = website.replace(i,'')
    return(website)
```

Comment: This wont remove other sub domains.

Comment: now it includes sub domains matching :)

Comment: Still doesn't support sftp, ports or any url that includes a path after the suffix, the duplicate offers much more robust solutions

Comment: Thank you Negar37 for the help. I went now with `tldextract`. That solved with with the least amount of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a custom Regex pattern as follows:

```
import re

website = "http://www.test.com"

url = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+.com') # custom Regex pattern

print(url.findall(website))
```

Output for all the examples in your description:

```
['test.com']
```

Feel free to put any special characters within `[]` in line 3, if required.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` is a bit short for domain name